# Structure of Keyword Driven framework in NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am trying to build simple keyword driven framework in NUnit with selenium. The problem is I can't find the way to build it since NUnit runs every method lying under `[Test]` attribute. Example:

```
Core browser;
Application xlApp; 

[SetUp]
public void Init()
{
    xlApp = new Application();
    browser = new Core();
}    

[Test]
public void Login()
{
   //implemenation
}

[Test]
public void Logout()
{
   //implemenation
}
```

Reading keywords from excel and want to run the test. How to execute the test based on the keyword? Where should I write the logic of getting keyword and running test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TestCaseSource] to driver single main test file with keyword data.  If you plan to maintain testcases in one sheet and keywords as next sheet, then you can map the test case sheet data to the main test.

So you will get different set of test based on the test case sheet data. Please refer [this blog](https://github.com/ObjectivityLtd/Test.Automation/wiki/NUnit-DataDriven-tests-from-Xml,-CSV-and-Excel-files) for data driving the test using excel or csv data. Also refer [this blog](http://www.brendanconnolly.net/data-driven-testing-with-nunit-3/) to get clear idea.

In the main test, you can write code to process the keywords belong to particular test.

Comment: Good one, not what I wanted exactly but will figure out the rest from that blog. Thanks!